# Create new array of arrays from key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array:

```
[{
    "name": "Category 1",
    "entries": [{
        "question": "Question 1",
        "answer": "Answer 1"
    }, {
        "question": "Question 2",
        "answer": "Answer 2"
    }, {
        "question": "Question 3",
        "answer": "Answer 3"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Category 2",
    "entries": [{
        "question": "Question 1",
        "answer": "Answer 1"
    }, {
        "question": "Question 2",
        "answer": "Answer 2"
    }, {
        "question": "Question 3",
        "answer": "Answer 3"
    }]
}]
```

What I want to do is create a new array of just the entries.

So I end up with this:

```
[{
    "question": "Question 1",
    "answer": "Answer 1"
}, {
    "question": "Question 2",
    "answer": "Answer 2"
}, {
    "question": "Question 3",
    "answer": "Answer 3"
}, {
    "question": "Question 1",
    "answer": "Answer 1"
}, {
    "question": "Question 2",
    "answer": "Answer 2"
}, {
    "question": "Question 3",
    "answer": "Answer 3"
}]
```

In PHP I would of just do a push into a new array... but in Ruby is it possible to use `group_by` or `collect` to achieve this?

Comment: When you give an example, it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = [{ "name": "Category 1",...]`). That way, readers can refer to the variable(s) (`arr`) in answers and comments without having to define it (them), and all readers will use the same variable(s). I suggest you edit your question to do that. Generally there's no need to do that for desired or expected output objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#`flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
array = [{
    "name": "Category 1",
    "entries": [{
        "question": "Question 1",
        "answer": "Answer 1"
    }, {
        "question": "Question 2",
        "answer": "Answer 2"
    }, {
        "question": "Question 3",
        "answer": "Answer 3"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Category 2",
    "entries": [{
        "question": "Question 1",
        "answer": "Answer 1"
    }, {
        "question": "Question 2",
        "answer": "Answer 2"
    }, {
        "question": "Question 3",
        "answer": "Answer 3"
    }]
}]
array.flat_map { |hash| hash[:entries] }
   #=> [{:question=>"Question 1", :answer=>"Answer 1"},
   #  {:question=>"Question 2", :answer=>"Answer 2"},
   #  {:question=>"Question 3", :answer=>"Answer 3"},
   #  {:question=>"Question 1", :answer=>"Answer 1"},
   #  {:question=>"Question 2", :answer=>"Answer 2"},
   #  {:question=>"Question 3", :answer=>"Answer 3"}]
```

Comment: Instead of `flat_map`, `map` and `flatten` can be used here to get exactly an array of hashes like `array.map {|hash| hash[:entries]}.flatten`

Comment: @dkp `flat_map` is about 2 times faster, that `map` + `flatten` :)

Comment: `[[{:question=>"Question 1", :answer=>"Answer 1"}, {:question=>"Question 2", :answer=>"Answer 2"}, {:question=>"Question 3", :answer=>"Answer 3"}], [{:question=>"Question 1", :answer=>"Answer 1"}, {:question=>"Question 2", :answer=>"Answer 2"}, {:question=>"Question 3", :answer=>"Answer 3"}]] `  - I thought `flat_map` would result array inside array here

Comment: @dkp, re your first comment, that's obvious, considering that `flat_map`'s *raison d'être* is to avoid the need for `map` and `flatten`.

Comment: Maybe just say "If `array` is your array," and delete `array`, which is a bit distracting.

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`flatten`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/flatten) would give you desired output:

```
your_array.map {|hash| hash[:entries]}.flatten

#=> [{:question=>"Question 1", :answer=>"Answer 1"},
# {:question=>"Question 2", :answer=>"Answer 2"},
# {:question=>"Question 3", :answer=>"Answer 3"},
# {:question=>"Question 1", :answer=>"Answer 1"},
# {:question=>"Question 2", :answer=>"Answer 2"},
# {:question=>"Question 3", :answer=>"Answer 3"}]
```